# Summoning Surge: do you put the event card in the discard before taking event action?

Tags: summoner-wars

The Deep Dwarve's Summoning Surge event card states:

> you may remove up to 3 cards from your Discard Pile and place them on top of your Magic Pile.

The Illusionary Warrior event says this:

> Choose a common Unit that is in your Magic Pile. Place the chose Unit adjacent to a Deep Dwarf Champion or Gem Mage that you control.

Because of this second event card, the cards that go into the magic pile may have a certain level of significance.

My question is:

**When you play the Summoning Surge event card, does the event card go into your Discard Pile first before adding 3 cards from the Discard to the Magic, OR do you take the 3 cards and THEN place the event card in the discard pile?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/summoner-wars/rules.pdf), page 17:

> If the effects from 2 Special Abilities or Event Cards ever trigger at the 
>   exact same time, the player whose turn it is determines in which order 
>   those effects will resolve.  Likewise if an attack ever Hits multiple Units 
>   at once the attacker chooses in which order they are Hit.

So, since it is **your** Event phase, you choose the order of event cards you played.

At page 7 of the rulebook, you also read:

> Event Cards are played 1 at a time and are resolved immediately. 
>   After playing an Event Card, place that card face-up in your Discard 
>   Pile.

So, when resolving Summoning Surge, you remove the 3 cards from your discard pile, place them in your magic pile, then discard the Summoning Surge. After that you resolve the Illusionary Warrior, maybe (probably, I guess) picking one of the 3 cards you just added to your magic pile.

Comment: I understand, but the issues isn't that two event cards are being played. One event is being played, but I'm not sure whether to discard the event card before taking the action.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I improved the answer  and I believe I answered your question now.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official FAQ version 1.3](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/59058/summoner-wars-faq-13):

> Q: What happens if 2 powers trigger at the same time?
>   A: The player whose turn it is determines in which order the Special Abilities will be resolved.

It seems since this happens on your turn, you can choose the order that is most benificial for you.

Comment: My question only arose on the first event because the second event is available. The issue isn't deciding which event to play first.